# Re-sequencing a list of tasks when a change is made manually

Tags: excel, sequence, sequential

I have a table with an list of tasks sequenced 1-41 in the first column.  I want to allow the sequence to be manually overridden by putting a task number in the middle column and have the sequence recalculated in the Resulting Sequence Column.

The issue revolves around sequential tasks being overridden.

The data is in a table so I'm trying to avoid array formulas, but at this point I'm open to anything.

If anyone knows a way to get a count of the number of sequential numbers in this list I would greatly appreciate it.

[Sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEbw.png)

I'm expecting the result to be what is in the Resulting Sequence column.

I know how to have it count and return the proper sequence number when the tasks that are changed are non-sequential.  Its a series of IF, MATCH and COUNTIF formulas based on cell values and counts of cells with numbers.  Its the sequential entries that screw it up.  the tasks that are offset by the sequence are offset by the count of sequential numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
=LET(manual,SORT(FILTER([Manual],[Manual]<>"")),
mrows,ROWS(manual),
mstarts,REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(mrows),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,IF(c=1,INDEX(manual,1),IF(INDEX(manual,c)<>INDEX(manual,c-1)+1,INDEX(manual,c),""))))),
fmstarts,FILTER(mstarts,mstarts<>""),
mends,REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(mrows),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,IF(c=mrows,INDEX(manual,mrows),IF(INDEX(manual,c+1)<>INDEX(manual,c)+1,INDEX(manual,c),""))))),
fmends,FILTER(mends,mends<>""),
lengths,fmends-fmstarts+1,
prevResult,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TRUE,(FILTER([Manual],ROW([Manual])<ROW())=""),FILTER([Result],ROW([Result])<ROW()),0,0,-1),0)+1,
offset,XLOOKUP(prevResult,fmstarts,lengths,0),
IF(@[Manual]<>"",@[Manual],prevResult+offset))
```

[image]

[image]